# Bash Script Fails During Jenkins Build But Does Not Fail Locally

Tags: linux, bash, jenkins, centos7, beyondcompare

I've been trying to debug this issue all day with no success.

Issue: Bash script executes successfully on a Linux CentOS7 VM (jenkins build agent) but fails during Jenkins build.

Here's the simple script.

```
#! /bin/bash
echo "before beyond compare command"
bcompare @"bc_report.ps1" "./Output_Base/<Folder_Name>" "./Output_Compare/<Folder Name>" "Report.html"
echo "after beyond compare command"
```

The output in the Jenkins build log is just:

```
before beyond compare command
after beyond compare command
```

When viewing the VM during the Jenkins build, I'm not seeing an artifact being produced. The user during the Jenkins build is Root, when executing the script locally, I'm also doing so as Root with success.

I'm pretty sure this is a Jenkins issue, just can't seem to figure it out. Anyone seen something similar?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Before that command, have you checked whether or not you are in the exact path you're expecting to be?

Comment: What @ewong said: maybe make sure to `cd` to the right directory inside the script.

Comment: To help debugging, change the last line to `echo "after beyond compare command ($?)"`, so that you can see the exit code of _bcompare_.

Comment: In addition, I would put a `type bcompare; set -x` between the first _echo_ and the _bcompare_. It seems unnecessary, but from it we can verify that (1) which _bcompare_ is executed, (2) **that** a _bcompare_ is executed, and (3) that stderr has not been accidentally thrown away somehow. Please make the suggested changes and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the feedback, I'm also learning new tricks on troubleshooting so thank you for that! The Answer provided by @chriskennedy, who is also an admin for Beyond Compare, is most likely the reason why beyond compare isn't executing anything when the script is ran through jenkins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beyond Compare 4 for Linux requires an X-Window/GUI session to run, even for scripts. As a cron job or in an SSH terminal without an X-Window client, Beyond Compare for Linux scripts will fail to run. This might be what is causing your Jenkins job to fail.

Beyond Compare 4 for Windows doesn't have the GUI session requirement for scripts. Beyond Compare 4 for Linux and macOS both require a GUI session for scripts. Removing the GUI session requirement for scripting on Linux and macOS is on the feature request list for a future version.

Comment: Thanks @Chris!

I believe this is most likely what is causing the script to "not do anything" when executing from Jenkins. For anyone dealing with this issue, I've also posted the problem on the Jenkins community board: https://community.jenkins.io/t/bash-script-fails-during-jenkins-build-but-does-not-fail-locally/2770/2